# Access elements from list snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to access an element in Snowflake. The input looks like as follows;

```
[{"address":"3285 RICHMOND AVE, STATEN ISLAND, NY, US, 10312-2112","duns":"081386564",
"industries":{"D&B Hoovers Industry Code":"1119 - Information Technology Services","D&B Standard Industry 
Code":"73730000 - COMP INTEGRATED SYS","NAICS":"541512 - Computer Systems Design Services","North American 
Industry Classification System 2012":"541512 - Computer Systems Design Services","UK SIC 2003":"72.22 - 
Other software consultancy and supply","UN Standards Products & Services Code":"81111503 - Systems integration
 design","US SIC (1987)":"7373 - Computer systems design"},"matchConfidence":10,"matchGrade":
"AAAAAZZAFAF","name":"EXCLUSIVE WEB SERVICES INC","operatingStatus":"Active"}]
```

May I know how can I access the value for `"North American Industry Classification System 2012"`.The desired output  is `"541512 - Computer Systems Design Services"`.

I tried ARRAY_SLICE but the output I got as follows;

```
[
  "[{\"address\":\"3285 RICHMOND AVE, STATEN ISLAND, NY, US, 10312-        2112\",\"duns\":\"081386564\",\"industries\":{\"D&B Hoovers Industry Code\":\"1119 - Information Technology Services\",\"D&B Standard Industry Code\":\"73730000 - COMP INTEGRATED SYS\",\"NAICS\":\"541512 - Computer Systems Design Services\",\"North American Industry Classification System 2012\":\"541512 - Computer Systems Design Services\",\"UK SIC 2003\":\"72.22 - Other software consultancy and supply\",\"UN Standards Products & Services Code\":\"81111503 - Systems integration design\",\"US SIC (1987)\":\"7373 - Computer systems design\"},\"matchConfidence\":10,\"matchGrade\":\"AAAAAZZAFAF\",\"name\":\"EXCLUSIVE WEB SERVICES INC\",\"operatingStatus\":\"Active\"}]"
```

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using a CTE just to get access to the `data`

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT PARSE_JSON('[
                        {"address":"3285 RICHMOND AVE, STATEN ISLAND, NY, US, 10312-2112",
                         "duns":"081386564",
                          "industries": {
                                "D&B Hoovers Industry Code":"1119 - Information Technology Services",
                                "D&B Standard Industry Code":"73730000 - COMP INTEGRATED SYS",
                                "NAICS":"541512 - Computer Systems Design Services",
                                "North American Industry Classification System 2012": "541512 - Computer Systems Design Services",
                                "UK SIC 2003":"72.22 - Other software consultancy and supply",
                                "UN Standards Products & Services Code":"81111503 - Systems integration design",
                                "US SIC (1987)":"7373 - Computer systems design"
                          },
                       "matchConfidence":10,
                       "matchGrade": "AAAAAZZAFAF",
                       "name":"EXCLUSIVE WEB SERVICES INC",
                       "operatingStatus":"Active"
                      }
                      ]') as json
)
```

then you want to use two FLATTEN's as there are two arrays, thus

```
SELECT d.json as json
    ,f.value AS f_value
    ,i.value AS i_value
FROM DATA d
    ,TABLE(FLATTEN(input=>d.json)) f
    ,TABLE(FLATTEN(input=>f.value:industries)) i
```

works, and if you just look at the last columns gives:

```
I_VALUE
"1119 - Information Technology Services"
"73730000 - COMP INTEGRATED SYS"
"541512 - Computer Systems Design Services"
"541512 - Computer Systems Design Services"
"72.22 - Other software consultancy and supply"
"81111503 - Systems integration design"
"7373 - Computer systems design"
```